# Conditional Variable to Check if a Match Has Been Found | Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to figure out how to write a conditional variable (basically something that would instantiate and store variable) to test whether or not a match has been found. The code aims to find two students that share two classes, checking the first then sending it to the second. The problem arises when it checks the student's class from different places in the list, resulting in multiple outputs of the same result. I would like to find a way to check whether or not something has been printed by making a specialized variable flip from a 0 to a 1, by concatinating the two student's names into a string, and naming a variable that string, instantiating it at 1. Then, I'd like either print, or fail if the variable is equal to 1. How would I do something like that? If it's not possible, what could be another solution?

```
students :-
    checkFirst(X, Y).

checkFirst(X, Y) :-
    enrolled(X, A),
    enrolled(Y, A),
    X \= Y,
    checkSecond(X, Y, A).
    
checkSecond(X, Y, A) :-
    enrolled(X, B),
    enrolled(Y, B),
    A \= B,
    atom_concat(X, Y, S),
    nl, write(X), write(' and '), write(Y), 
    write(' share two classes together.'), fail.
```

I've tried using b_setval and b_getval, but I get instantiation errors every time I try to call the command.

Comment: The cleanest way, if possible, is to reduce your search space to make sure that you only find unique solutions in the first place. It may be enough to change `X \= Y` and `A \= B` to `X @< Y` and `A @< B`.